# Mule 4 expression to pass datetime in url

Tags: date, datetime, parsing, dataweave, mule4

I am re writing a Mule 3 application to Mule 4 and my api calls the other api which has filter condition like this in the url ?filter=(date-greater-than(VOD_DATA,'#[server.dateTime.plusDays(-Integer.parseInt(${num.of.days})).format("yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss")]')) I need this expression in mule 4 since server. dateTime doesn't work, I am trying with this expression (date-greater-than(VOD_DATA,'now() as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"} + |P30D|') and it is throwing me an error as illegal character found. Can anyone help me with the expression to parse the filter in url ?

Comment: How do you form your URL to call the API with filter? I think it is needed to do percent-encoding first before passing it to your API first as it has reserved characters.

Answer (score 1):

The expression seems correct. It is missing the expression delimiters (#[...]) and convert the result to a string just in case:

```
(date-greater-than(VOD_DATA,#[(now() as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"} + |P30D|) as String])
```

Comment: It is still not working, I am getting this error message                                              Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in fragment at index ?filter=(date-greater-than(VOD_DATA,'#[(now()%20as%20DateTime%20{format:%20"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"}%20+%20|P30D|)%20as%20String]')

Comment: Where are you using this expression? Please attach the XML of the connector where you are using it.